# (mysqld), uid 88 inumber 281675 on /: filesystem full

Tags: freebsd, swap

I created a swap file that was a little to big. So I deleted it. The swap file is gone, but the free space is never reallocated.
I have rebooted, fdisk is no help, not sure where to go from here. The file is deleted.

error:

```
(mysqld), uid 88 inumber 281675 on /: filesystem full


[\u@vader:/root] # du -sh /usr/
4.8G    /usr/



[\u@vader:/root] # ls -l /usr
total 88
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   8192 Apr 11 23:07 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    512 Nov 11 21:03 games
drwxr-xr-x  53 root  wheel   6144 Nov 11 21:03 include
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  13312 Apr 11 22:51 lib
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  13824 Apr 11 22:51 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel    512 Nov 11 21:03 libdata
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   1536 Dec 31 15:21 libexec
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel    512 Apr 13 00:19 local
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    512 Nov 11 21:03 obj
drwxr-xr-x  70 root  wheel   2048 Apr 11 23:14 ports
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   5120 Apr 11 22:51 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  32 root  wheel    512 Nov 11 21:03 share
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    512 Nov 11 21:03 src



[\u@vader:/root] # du -sh /* | sort -rn
477M    /boot
256K    /libexec
210M    /home
 21M    /tmp
 12M    /devd.core
9.3M    /lib
8.6M    /dhclient.core
8.0K    /COPYRIGHT
7.7M    /rescue
5.9M    /sbin
4.8G    /usr
4.0K    /proc
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /entropy
2.6M    /etc
2.5K    /dev
2.1M    /root
1.2M    /bin
1.2G    /var
  0B    /sys
```

fstb:

```
[\u@vader:/root] # cat /etc/fstab
/dev/vtbd0p2 / ufs rw 0 0
#md99   none    swap    sw,file=/usr/swap0      0       0
```

How do I reallocate my new free space that won't free up?

***updated***

```
# df -i
/dev/vtbd0p2  15230472 15140800 -1128764   108%  411454 1572544   21%   /
devfs                1        1        0   100%       0       0  100%   /dev
```

Comment: Post the output of `df -i`.

Comment: @EEAA updated the question